# Numerically inverting an integral

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

I have an increasing function $H:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$, and a function G defined as
$$G(t)=\int_0^t H(s)ds.$$

The function $H$ has the proprty that $H(0)=0$.

I need a numerical method to find t, given that I know $G(t)=x$ for some $x\in[0,\infty)$.

I have seen a similar question asked here: [Numerical Solution to Inverse Integral (Pseudo Random Number Generation)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38719/numerical-solution-to-inverse-integral-pseudo-random-number-generation)
but there was no reference and I'm not sure I understand why it works.

Comment: Is there something wrong with Newton's method? The relevant iteration reads $t_{n+1}=t_n-\frac{G(t_n)-x}{H(t_n)}$. It shouldn't take long to converge for an increasing convex function.

Comment: Is a formula for $G$ available as well, or does the integral have to be computed numerically from $H$?

Comment: The formula for $G$ is unknown, so yes would have to be computed numerically from $H$.

Comment: I think Newton's method should be fine for most functions $H$ I would use. But suppose there is some $H$ that means computing $G(t_n)$ takes a long time, is there any other method that would give a reasonable approximation for $t$?

Answer (score 6):

If $H$ is continuous, $T(x)$  defined by $\int_0^{T(x)} H(s)\; ds = x$ satisfies the differential equation $$ \dfrac{dT}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{H(T)}$$
and standard numerical methods for differential equations can be used.

Comment: Nice idea! @Alice, could you comment on how that worked for your problem?

Comment: For this differential equation, you would have $T(0)=0$ as the initial condition. The problem I then have is that I am actually looking at functions $H$ such that $H(0)=0$. Would this be a problem when trying to solve this ODE since $\frac{dT}{dx}$ is not defined at the IC? (I realise this info should really have been in the initial question, I'll edit it now.)

Comment: @Alice Proceeding directly, that creates a problem for you indeed. But you can estimate $T(x)$ for small $x$ using some other method (for example, Newton's method, starting from a *nonzero* initial condition) and then use Robert Israel's suggestion for larger $x$, using that other estimate as your initial condition.

Comment: Or just compute $\int_0^{t_0} H(s)\; ds = x_0$ for some given $t_0$ and use initial condition $T(x_0) = t_0$.